# JPA Error a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I have a table and JPA Entity  called State (of a Country) and through JPA, I am trying to write a code for a User (Entity) to register on the website. Clearly, there is a one-to-one relationship between User and State (a User belongs to only one State). Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE")
public class State implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    
    
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
```

And User code is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

....
@OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private State state;
```

The database tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bjm`.`STATE` (
  `CODE` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `POST_CODE_PREFIX` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `LANG` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bjm`.`USER` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FIRSTNAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LASTNAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_STATE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`STATE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `bjm`.`STATE` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, when I try to create/register User in my JSF2 application, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: org.bjm.model.State
```

I don't want to create a new State record in the DB. They are already there (as reference data) and just need an assignment to the User via the foreign key.

May be I a missing something, but I need a resolution. Any constructive comment would be of extreme help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly, there is a one-to-one relationship between User and State (a User belongs to only one State)

Well, clearly this is **wrong**. This is classic `@ManyToOne`, because many users are from the same state. It should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements Serializable {

    // (...)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID")
    private State state;
```